# Using custom view in alert with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uialertcontroller

How can I make an **alert** containing custom view which contains a **uitableview**?

UserInteraction should be disabled everywhere in the background. As soon as a row gets selected, the alert window should disappear.

```
let popup : PopupVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopupVC") as! PopupVC
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popup)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And this gives no errors but showing a different view with no interaction.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: i added now, but the thing is i don't want to instantiate a new view controller, i want to be able to use uiAlertView with my custom view if such thing exists. @RomanSausarnes

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to modify the default `UIAlertController`. But you can use for example [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView). This basically creates custom `UIAlertController`s that look exactly like the built-in, but you can edit the content view.

**Example (copied from the Readme):**

```
let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
spinner.startAnimating()

let alert = AlertController(title: "Title", message: "Please wait...")
alert.contentView.addSubview(spinner)

spinner.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(alert.contentView.centerXAnchor).active = true
spinner.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(alert.contentView.topAnchor).active = true
spinner.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(alert.contentView.bottomAnchor).active = true

alert.present()
```

You can basically add everything as subview of `alert.contentView`

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible to replace the `UIAlertController` behavior, but you can extend it:

```
extension UIAlertController {
    static func showCustomAlert() {

    }

    static func showCustomAlert(data: [AnyObject]) {

    }
}
```

Within the first function you can call your custom view controller. And within the second you can pass some data to it, for example when your custom view controller shows a table view that needs data to show.

So when you need to show the alert you just can do:

```
UIAlertController.showCustomAlert()
```

Note that the `static` keyword allows you to call the function without creating an instance of `UIAlertController`.

Comment: ´UIAlertView´ is deprecated since iOS 8. You should use `UIAlertController` instead.

Comment: Yes, it is a typo, I have updated the code. But anyway I believe the solution proposed is explanatory for what he need.